# TeamCity not getting some new files pushed into Git

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

Recently I've added a few JS files to my web project: `WebProject.csproj`

I have a CI definition in TeamCity set to use MSBuild to build the solution with the following command-line parameters:

```
/p:OutDir=%teamcity.build.workingDir%\ReleaseBuild\;Configuration=Release;UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True;PipelineDependsOnBuild=False
```

This is so I can easily do a deployment in a later step if needed for other build definitions.

However, some of the recent js files I've added are failing MSBuild because it can't do the pipline copy because they don't exist in the folder they exist in within git...

I have "Clean all files before build" set as seen in the TeamCity log below:

```
[20:27:33]Updating sources: server side checkout (5s)
[20:27:33][Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: "Clean all files before build" turned on
[20:27:33][Updating sources] Transferring cached clean patch for VCS root: GitProjectVCS
[20:27:37][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred: 36.49Mb total
[20:27:37][Updating sources] Removing C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d002fb661417bf57
[20:27:37][Updating sources] Updating C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d002fb661417bf57
```

When I do a fresh `git clone` the js files exist in the Scripts folder just like I added them. However when I check the work folder that TeamCity puts all the files from git into the js files don't exist in the Scripts folder...

Am I missing something?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am getting a similar issue, did you ever found an answer for this?